# How to iterate over all pair combinations in a list in bash?

Tags: bash

I define a list in bash like this:

```
list="element1 element_2 my_element_3 element04"
```

and I want to do a loop where I iterate through all possible pair combinations. In Perl, I would use a while/foreach with a shift on the list like this:

```
while (my $element1 = shift (@list)) {
  foreach my $element2 (@list) {
      print "$element1 - $element2\n";
  }
}
```

I don't want the same element in the pair and don't care about the order of the pairs, so if the list is "A B C", the result should be:

```
A - B
A - C
B - C
```

How can I do the equivalent in bash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest approach seems to be to use positional parameters.

```
set -- value1 value2 "value with spaces"
for a; do
    shift
    for b; do
        printf "%s - %s\n" "$a" "$b"
    done
done
```

Comment: hmmmm, just to clarify, I don't want the same element in the pair and don't care about the order of the pairs, I've edited my question now.

Comment: I just saw the shift in your original question as well.  Updated answer to match.

Comment: This `for` loop looked odd to me. In case others are wondering, like I was (and I've just had to look it up), if no `...in <values>` is specified, the loop processes each positional parameter that is set (`$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc). I mean, it seems obvious now, but there you go. Thank you @jw013 for showing me this feature!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think about your problem is:  if you had (i,j) indexes for each item in your list, you would only be interested in the set of items above (or below) the diagonal (ie, where i>j).

If you did want all combinations, then you only have to test where i!=j.

I wanted to do a similar thing: generate all possible orderings of 4 items.  `For` loops nested to a depth of 4 would not be very pretty, and an elegant conditional didn't come to mind, but this solution did:

```
$ for combo in  {en,fa,sp,ru}{en,fa,sp,ru}{en,fa,sp,ru}{en,fa,sp,ru}; do echo $combo; done | egrep -v 'en.*en|fa.*fa|sp.*sp|ru.*ru' 
enfaspru
enfarusp
enspfaru
ensprufa
enrufasp
enruspfa
faenspru
faenrusp
faspenru
faspruen
faruensp
faruspen
spenfaru
spenrufa
spfaenru
spfaruen
spruenfa
sprufaen
ruenfasp
ruenspfa
rufaensp
rufaspen
ruspenfa
ruspfaen
```

Answer (score -2):

dump the output to standard out, pipe to sort -u